# Processing CSV files one by one in pyspark

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark

CSV files are placed in HDFS folder. All the files are of same schema. I have to read the CSV files and create partitions based on file name. Is there a way to read all the CSV files in Dataframe and process it one by one?

```
File name : file1_20200417123.csv
Parition : year_month=202004 day=17

File name : file2_20190212208.csv
Partition : year_month=201902 day=12
```

Need to read these 2 files and create partitions and save the data to respective partitions.

Comment: looks like each file contains data from different time range, would that assumption be correct? Also, is there a timestamp field in the data, that's in sync with this assumption?

Comment: @Bitswazsky file name contains time range and it will be in sync. I have edited it now. I need to get only the YYYYMMdd from file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the csv file using **`spark.read.csv`**

- Using **`input_file_name()`** function we can get the filename for each record.
- Split the filename with `_` and extract the last element.
- Using **`substring (or) date_format (or) from_unixtime(unix_timestamp)`** functions we can extract **year_month,day** and add as columns to the dataframe.

---

**`Example:`**

```
#sample data in csv directory

file1_20200417123.csv
file2_20190212208.csv

$cat * csv
id,name
1,"a"
id,name
2,"b"
```

---

```
spark.read.option("header","true").csv("csv").\
withColumn("filename",reverse(split(input_file_name(),'_'))[0]).\
withColumn("year_month",substring(col("filename"),0,6)).\
withColumn("day",substring(col("filename"),7,2)).\
drop("filename").\
show(10,False)
#+---+----+----------+---+
#|id |name|year_month|day|
#+---+----+----------+---+
#|2  |b   |201902    |12 |
#|1  |a   |202004    |17 |
#+---+----+----------+---+
```